# Lambda use case confusion

Tags: python

I've been playing around with Celery / Django. In their example celery.py file there is the following line

```
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS, force=True)
```

Where `lambda:settings.INSTALLED_APPS` is the actual parameter for the formal parameter `packages` in `autodiscover_tasks()`. And `settings.INSTALLED_APPS` is a tuple.

`autodiscover_tasks()` then either calls the function it was passed or directly assigns the variable it was given in one of its first lines...

```
packages = packages() if callable(packages) else packages
```

So my question is. I just don't get why this was done this way. It seems very redundant. Why not just pass `settings.INSTALLED_APPS` as the tuple god wanted it to be. Why pass an anonymous function that calls it instead? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since Celery is asyncrhonous it is not fixed that `settings.Installed_Apps` will not change while performing other computations, so wrapping it inside a `lambda` encapsulates it value as a reference until it gets called.

**EDIT (adding an example as commented):**

```
setting.INSTALLED_APPS = 10
app.autodiscover_tasks(settings.INSTALLED_APPS, force=True) #is called with installed_apps = 10, so it give you an output.
```

now think of this, while `app.autodiscover_tasks`is being called and its internall computations are made some other thing is being computed, and `setting.INSTALLED_APPS` now `= 8`, since you did use the variable, your call is using `10` instead of '8', but encapsulating it into the `lambda` (`app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS, force=True)`) it will get the value **when** he needs it, synchronizing with its actual value wich should be `8`.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Adding on to Daniel's answer, here's a rather minimal example to showcase "late evaluation" by passing a callable.

```
>>> def foo(arg):
...     return lambda: arg() if callable(arg) else arg
```

This is a function that returns another function in order to fake asynchronous execution.

Build two functions:

```
>>> foo_arg = 3
>>> foo1 = foo(foo_arg)
>>> foo2 = foo(lambda: foo_arg)
```

Change `foo_arg` *after* creation of `foo1` and `foo2`:

```
>>> foo_arg = 4
```

Call the functions:

```
>>> foo1()
3
>>> foo2()
4
```

`foo1` uses the old `foo_arg` it was constructed with, `foo2` calls the anonymous function to get the current value of `foo_arg`.